# Converting Saved model to tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow, model, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I can't install the TensorFlow converter, cuz I can't install tf-nightly-2.0 preview . Whenever I try installing it , it says "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf-nightly-2.0-preview" . I've set my py version to 3.6.0 and 3.6.8 too . Can't I use colab for this conversion?

Comment: What command line are you using ?

Comment: Recommended to install stable version tf-nightly. `pip install tf-nightly`. Thanks!